# How can i move any shape on view, when i touch and move in the screen?

Tags: android, canvas

I am using canvas. I am having some problems when i move my view on canvas.
I have the custom view class. `RectangleDrawView` and `LineDrawView` extend android view.

What i want is i am able touch any shapes, and then move to another position on view. I can only touch `LineDrawView` but can not touch `RectangleDrawView`.

**Layout**

```
          <com.echopen.asso.echopen.CanvasDraw.RectangleDrawView 
             android:id="@+id/draw_view"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>


         <com.echopen.asso.echopen.CanvasDraw.LineDrawView
             android:id="@+id/line_draw_view"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
```

[This is my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4b5q.png)

Please help me!
Thanks so much